# How to enforce that arbitrary class methods have the same signature in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, rest

So I'm writing the front-end implementation of an API in TypeScript, and I want to implement a mock version of the API I can turn on conditionally, without calling the mock methods explicitly. As an example:

```
class API {
    public isMock: boolean = false;

    public getObjects(...args: RequestParameters): ResponseParameters {
        if (this.isMock) {
            return this.mock.getObjects(...args);
        }
        //do real request logic

    }

    private mock = {
        getObjects: (...args: RequestParameters): ResponseParameters => {
            //do mock request logic
        }
    }
}
```

This illustrates what I want the shape of the class to be, but what I would really like is some `MockableAPI` interface that I can implement that specifically enforces that if I write a real (or mock) method, I will have to write a corresponding mock (or real) method in the appropriate section, but without having to specify ahead of time what the keys or signatures of these methods be. So if down the road I write a `getWidget` method, I will get a syntax error if I don't write a corresponding method in the mock section. I though about using an index type with generics, but it doesn't seem to shake out the way I want it. Also, not sure how private vs public will shake out in typescript.

I've already attempted something like the following:

```
type GenericAPIMethod<T, R> = (...args: T) => R

interface MockableAPI {
    [methodKey: string]: GenericAPIMethod<>
}
```

But of course this doesn't help anything, because the index typing screws with my ability to type the mock block separately, and I would need to know the generic types ahead of time, which I am trying to avoid.

Of course, if somebody has a good alternative way of doing this (preferably without an external library), I would be interested in that as well.

Comment: Just omit mock then? https://tsplay.dev/wR73xN